# combine csv headers into new one

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)  library for parsing CSV files, but I have to map tow columns to a single one that contains the data for each one: like {name}: {firstName} {lastName}

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: In your backing class, have read-write properties for `FirstName` and `LastName`, but also have a read-only property that looks like `public string Name => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";`

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you were looking for?

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Id,FirstName,LastName");
            writer.WriteLine("1,Bob,Barker");
            writer.WriteLine("2,Davey,Jones");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooClassMap>();

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class FooClassMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name).ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField("FirstName") + " " + row.GetField("LastName"));
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```